# How to apply an external font for a complete Android app?

Tags: android, fonts, external

I want to change the font of my complete app!
But I don't know how to access the complete application.
I have a way to access a text by Id, how can I change the code to access the whole App?

```
public class ExternalFont extends Activity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         String fontPath = "fonts/FreeUniversal-Regular.ttf";
         TextView txtUniversal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.universal);
         Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
         txtUniversal.setTypeface(tf);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change all typeface for all TextView in app you should create custom style then add it into AppTheme style.

```
`<style name="customTextVeiw" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
<item name"fontFamilt">@font/custom_free_universal_regular</item>`
```

then add this style inside style.xml file inside AppTheme style.

```
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/customTextVeiw</item>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct way in which you can change the typeface of all the TextViews you are using in your app by just changing the default typeface.

What you can do is create your own custom TextView and set typeface on it as suggested by #josedlujan. But the flaw in that approach is that each time a TextView object will be created, a new Typeface object will be created which is extremely bad for RAM usage (A Typeface object typically varies from 8-13 kb for typefaces like Roboto). So it is better to cache your Typeface once it has got loaded.

Step 1: Create a Typeface cache for your app -

```
public enum Font {

  // path to your font asset
  Y("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

  public final String name;
  private Typeface typeface;

  Font(String s) {
    name = s;
  }

  public Typeface getTypeface(Context context) {

    if (typeface != null) return typeface;
    try {
      return typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static Font fromName(String fontName) {

    return Font.valueOf(fontName.toUpperCase());
  }
```

Step 2: Define your own custom attribute "customFont" in attrs.xml for your CustomTextView

```
attrs.xml - 
<declare-styleable name="CustomFontTextView">
    <attr name="customFont"/>
</declare-styleable>


<com.packagename.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/some_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:customFont="rl"/>
```

Step 3: Create your own custom TextView

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends TextView {

public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomFontTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

  if (attrs == null) {
    return;
  }

  TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFontTextView, 0 ,0);
  String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomFontTextView_customFont);

  String textStyle = attrs.getAttributeValue(styleScheme, styleAttribute);

  if (fontName != null) {
    Typeface typeface = Font.fromName(fontName).getTypeface(context);
    if (textStyle != null) {
      int style = Integer.decode(textStyle);
      setTypeface(typeface, style);
    } else {
      setTypeface(typeface);
    }
  }
  a.recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Font for all app text you should use the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher.
To add fonts as resources, perform the following steps in the Android Studio:

- Right-click the res folder and go to New > Android resource directory.
  The New Resource Directory window appears.
- In the Resource type list, select font, and then click OK.
- Add your font files in the font folder like this free_universal_regular.ttf
  you should start your font with lower and under score instead of -.

**Creating a font family**

- Right-click the font folder and go to New > Font resource file. The New Resource File window appears.
- Enter the file name e.g: custom_free_universal_regular.xml , and then click OK. The new font resource XML opens in the editor.
- add this in custom_free_universal_regular.xml file.

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/free_universal_regular" /> </font-family>`

Now we can use this font family anywhere in our app like this
For e.g for all app use it inside the style.xml
`<style name="BaseTheme" parent=""> <item name="fontFamily">@font/custom_free_universal_regular</item>` 
or in a specific element use it like this
`<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fontFamily="@font/custom_free_universal_regular"/>`

I hope that could help.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own Textview with custom style.

Example:

```
public class YourTextView extends TextView {

    public YourTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public YourTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public YourTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

You can use in yours XML.

Comment: He asked how to apply custom font for the complete application.